# String to byte array conversion varies from windows and ubuntu

Tags: java, arrays, byte

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {       
        byte[] bytearray = new byte[]{1, -30, 48, 50, 49, 48};

        for (int i = 0; i < bytearray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(bytearray[i]+", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Length of byteArray before : "+bytearray.length);

        String st = new String(bytearray);
        System.out.println("String value : "+ st);  

        bytearray = st.getBytes();

        for (int i = 0; i < bytearray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(bytearray[i]+", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Length of byteArray after : "+bytearray.length);
    }
```

this is my program if i am executing this on windows i am getting exactly same bytes as previous but on ubuntu, it's giving extra 2 bytes I didn't understand it ? why ?

which method should I use to get same array on ubuntu ?

Comment: I think you can fix that by using the same character set. Here is an example:  `new String(bytearray, "UTF-8")` and `str.getBytes("UTF-8")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what the documentation says for [String constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[]%29):

> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using
>   the platform's default charset.

And what it says for [getBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29):

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's
>   default charset, storing the result into a new byte array.

So, why do you get different behavior in different systems? Because their default charsets are different. You can get the default charset using `Charset.defaultCharset()`.

Comment: I have tried this it's giving default charset as UTF-8, and still the problem exist...!

Comment: Try using String st = new String(bytearray, "ISO-8859-1") and bytearray = st.getBytes( "ISO-8859-1")

Comment: Even though you can do this, it's likely to be a bad idea unless you know the bytes are a String encoded as ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I thought you were using valid encoded data.

Your bytes are not valid UTF-8, so if you have different versions of Java it may handle this differently.

```
new byte[]{1, -30, 48, 50, 49, 48}
```

In short your should be using text to attempt to store binary data. This will only confuse you (and waste memory)

Comment: I am working on ubuntu and it's throwing  java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException if I am using StandardCharsets.UTF_8

Comment: @Shailesh There is something wrong with your JVM then, as it's a standard builtin encoding all JVMs have to have which is why it's in the StandardCharsets. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html note: If you use a String you have to write `"UTF-8"`

Comment: it's giving default charset as utf-8, i have tried using "UTF-8" still it's not working..! are you sure there is something wrong with my JVM ?

Comment: sorry but I didn't get that ideone.com link program how it shows JVM is wrong ?

Comment: @Shailesh Sorry, I realised what the problem is. You can't be encoding binary data as text unless you like confusion (or you really know what you are doing) I strongly suggest you avoid trying to do this.  Different versions of Java and different encoding handle invalid encoded bytes differently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126520/discussion-between-shailesh-and-peter-lawrey).